# Load specific tab based on url query

Tags: php, jquery, tabs

My URL has query called "cct_action".  This can either equal "add" or "edit".
My page contains several tabs.  I'd like to specify which tab to be active based on the cct_action.

I'm able to define the cct_action using PHP GET Method then assign it to a var in js.
`$editpage = $_GET['cct_action']; var editpage = '<?php echo $editpage; ?>';`

The active tab has a class called .active added to it.  I'm having issues figuring out how to do something like:
`if (editpage == 'add') { ??? }`

Everything I looked up online pertained to tabs of a browser so my efforts have been in vain.

Comment: You can conditionally add `.active` to your HTML, like `echo '<div id="AddTab" class="' . ($editpage == 'add') ? ' .active' : '' . '"></div>';`.

Comment: i never heard of "jquery tabs" do you mean jqueryUI ?

Comment: @johnSmith The tabs are just html.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the direction @skip

To solve this I had to addClass and removeClass for the default active tab.  Then for some reason the tabs wouldn't switch back and forth on click so I had to add a rule to add and remove class on click:

```
if (editpage === "add") {
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#client_informaiton']").removeClass("active");
$(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#extra_tab']").addClass("active");
$("#client_informaiton").removeClass("show");
$("#extra_tab").addClass("show");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#extra_tab']").click(function(){
        $(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#extra_tab']").addClass("active");
        $("#extra_tab").addClass("show");
        $(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#client_informaiton']").removeClass("active");
        $("#client_informaiton").removeClass("show");
  });   
    $(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#client_informaiton']").click(function(){
        $(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#extra_tab']").removeClass("active");
        $("#extra_tab").removeClass("show");
        $(".cx-tab__button[data-content-id='#client_informaiton']").addClass("active");
        $("#client_informaiton").addClass("show");
});
});
}
</script>
```